# Change visual of histogram from image using matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to present a histogram from an image in Python.
Doing some research, I found a way of doing it using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html). So, I just do this:

```
im = plt.array(Image.open('Mean.png').convert('L'))
plt.figure()
plt.hist(im, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
plt.savefig("Histogram.png")
```

But I didn't like what I got:

[image: Histogram]

The bars are not green, and it's kind of complicated to read the histogram. I could not even figure out if the x axis is the number of points and y axis the rgb color or the inverse... :S
I would like to know if somebody knows how could I turn this histogram more readable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the histogram you have to flatten your image:

```
img = np.asarray(Image.open('your_image').convert('L'))
plt.hist(img.flatten(), facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
```

Since you converted the image to grayscale with `convert('L')` the x axis is the grayscale level from 0-255 and the y axis is the number of pixels.

You can also control the number of bins using the `bins` parameter:

```
plt.hist(img.flatten(), bins=100, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
```

Comment: Do you know how could I do this passing an list of list? In this case, I can't use the flatten method, but doing this _plt.hist(self.data, bins=10, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)_, I got something like the image that I posted before. I don't get it. :S

Comment: @pceccon You have to pass in a one dimensional structure. If you have a list of lists you have to flatten in somehow... Many possible solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python). The easiest, but not the fastest would be just to do `plt.hist(sum(self.data), ...)`